# I did a simple irc bot how can i send a message to the channel after joined a channel?

Tags: c#

This is the code :

```
private void connectToIrc()
        {
            //Connect to irc server and get input and output text streams from TcpClient.
            nick = textBox1.Text;
            owner = textBox2.Text;
            server = textBox3.Text;
            port = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            chan = "#" + textBox5.Text;
            sock.Connect(server, port);//server, port);

            richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                ColorText.AppendText(richTextBox1, "Server: ", Color.Green);
                ColorText.AppendText(richTextBox1, server+"          ", Color.Red);
                ColorText.AppendText(richTextBox1, "Port: ", Color.Green);
                ColorText.AppendText(richTextBox1, port.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, Color.Red);
            });
            if (!sock.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect!");
                return;
            }
            input = new System.IO.StreamReader(sock.GetStream());
            output = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sock.GetStream());

             //Starting USER and NICK login commands 
         output.Write(
            "USER " + nick + " 0 * :" + owner + "\r\n" +
            "NICK " + nick + "\r\n"
         );
         output.Flush();

         //Process each line received from irc server
         //buf = input.ReadLine();
         while ((buf = input.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
             buf = buf + Environment.NewLine;
             //Display received irc message
             //Console.WriteLine(buf);
             richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
             {
                 ColorText.AppendText(richTextBox1, buf,Color.Black);
             });
             if (buf.StartsWith("ERROR")) break;

             //Send pong reply to any ping messages
             if (buf.StartsWith("PING ")) { output.Write(buf.Replace("PING", "PONG") + "\r\n"); output.Flush(); }
             if (buf[0] != ':') continue;

             //After server sends 001 command, we can set mode to bot and join a channel
             if (buf.Split(' ')[1] == "001")
             {
                 output.Write(
                   "MODE " + nick + " +B\r\n" +
                   "JOIN " + chan + "\r\n" + "PRIVMSG " + chan + " :hello"
                 );
                 output.Flush();
             }
             buf = input.ReadLine();
         }

       }
```

I added this part to the code: + "PRIVMSG " + chan + " :hello"
But it does nothing i dont see any "hello" in the channel.

I used the example in this site :

http://jakash3.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/simple-vb-net-and-csharp-irc-client/

The C# example.

How can i send a message to the channel after joined one ? I want to send one message and if its working next step is to add messages in queue and they will be send automatic one by one.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Just because you sent to the server that you JOIN'ed it, doesnt mean you are instantly in the channel. You need to wait until you are in the actual channel, (wait for the JOIN command back from the server) and then send the privmsg.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot \r\n at the end of PRIVMSG command.

Comment: Nickolay i did: "JOIN " + chan + "\r\n" + "PRIVMSG " + chan + " :hello\r\n"     Added \r\n in the end and still i dont see the hello in the channel. Why ?

Comment: If i type through the program mirc in the channel when i enter the server and channel in a another nick name and type there :jello then in my Form on my c# program window i see hello but what i want to do is the other way. I want that it will send automatic the word hello from my program to the channel so everyone in the channel will see the word hello.  Now it will work if i type in the channel :hello and only i will see it in my program. I want that when i run my program after it connected to the server and entered the channel it will send automatic a message to the channel : Hello Everyone

Comment: This PRIVMSG is not sending from my side to the channel. Its making that if i type in the channel :hello then i see in my side hello. I want to make it will send from my program to the channel the word hello. So if in the channel there are 20 ppl now they are all will see the word Hello